# Soap1.2 with axis1.4 client and wsdl4j

Tags: java, soap, axis, wsdl2java, soap1.2

I have a soap dynamic client built with axis 1.4 jar and wsdl4j. If I try to parse a wsdl with Soap1.2 element it doesn't work because is not supported.

Is there a simple way to add the support to Soap1.2?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a stack trace you could share with us?

Comment: The issue is that the actual code is not able to parse soapaddress12 element present in wsdl. So it is casted to UnknownExtensibilityElement.

Comment: Is there any source code you could share?